# Deleted Rows Daily

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

I have a database table from which same data under a certain condition are lost at a specific time daily as if such statement is performed:

```
delete * from table where category=1
```

I'd like to list all delete actions on this table through a SQL script to know how records are deleted exactly and by which statement, user and time of deletion.

Does anyone have such script? Or did anyone have similar case and can advise?

The SQL version is Server 2008 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AFTER DELETE` trigger on the table to log deletions in another table with user and time it was performed.

Using some advanced tricks you can extract the query text which deleted the rows, but I'm not sure that it is possible inside a trigger.

The trigger might look like this

```
CREATE TABLE YourLogTable
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  [User] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT suser_sname(),
  [SqlText] NVARCHAR(MAX),
  [any other interesting columns from deleted rows]
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [TR.AD@YourTable]
ON YourTable
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sqlText NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @sqlText = txt.Text
  FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) txt
  WHERE session_id = @@SPID

  INSERT YourLogTable([SqlText], [any other interesting columns from deleted rows])
  SELECT @SqlText, [any other interesting columns from deleted rows]
  FROM DELETED

END
```

Comment: Can you guide me to the trigger script?

Comment: Updated answer with the script

Comment: Updated with possibility to view the current query

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the trigger and the log table. Hope that works.

Comment: @AmiraKamel - the best thanks are always vote up and accept the answer 8-)

Comment: A problem happened when a db user tried to delete rows from the table, saying he has no permissions. Once I stopped the trigger, he could delete from this table. Any idea?

Comment: try to remove everything about SqlText (statement which begins with SELECT @sqlText)

Comment: Same result...Can't delete permission issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6350/discussion-between-oleg-dok-and-amira-kamel)

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a short-term debugging issue, the easiest way to address this is probably to run SQL Server Profiler, with filters set to capture the data you're interested in. No code changes that way.

For best performance, try to run SQL Profiler on a machine other than the DB server, if you can.